# PocketSphinx OSError: [Errno -9981] Input overflowed PyAudio

Tags: python, pyaudio, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

First I want to tell the tools that I use:

*1. Raspberry pi 3b+

2. ReSpeaker 4Mic Array Circular (Mic)
3. Linux Debian "Buster"
4. Thonny Python IDE*

My problem is every time I try to run my code, it always gives me an error

```
[Errno -9981] Input overflowed
```

But when I run code and immediately say a word, it can recognize
then the error happens, I already try using my own lm and dict but the
the result is same, I'm a newbie so any answer is really thankful, this is my code :

---

```
from os import environ, path

from pocketsphinx import *
from sphinxbase import *

MODELDIR = "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pocketsphinx/model"

config = Decoder.default_config()
audio_device='plughw:1,0'
config.set_string('-hmm', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us'))
config.set_string('-lm', path.join(MODELDIR, 'en-us.lm.bin'))
config.set_string('-dict', path.join(MODELDIR, 'cmudict-en-us.dict'))
config.set_string('-logfn', '/dev/null')

decoder = Decoder(config)

import pyaudio
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paInt16,
                channels=1,
                rate=16000 ,#rate=16000,
                input=True,
                frames_per_buffer=1024,
                input_device_index =2)
stream.start_stream()

in_speech_bf = False
decoder.start_utt()
print("Check")
while True:
    buf = stream.read(1024)
    if buf:
        decoder.process_raw(buf, False, False)
        print("CHECKPOINT 1")
        if decoder.get_in_speech() != in_speech_bf:
            in_speech_bf = decoder.get_in_speech()
            print("CHECKPOINT 2")
            if not in_speech_bf:
                decoder.end_utt()
                print ('Result:', decoder.hyp().hypstr)  
                decoder.start_utt()
    else:
        break
decoder.end_utt()
```

---

And this is the output

---

```
Check

CHECKPOINT 1

CHECKPOINT 1

CHECKPOINT 2

CHECKPOINT 1

CHECKPOINT 1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/pocketRecognition/NYOBAINN.py", line 42, in <module>
    buf = stream.read(1024)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pyaudio.py", line 608, in read
    return pa.read_stream(self._stream, num_frames,
exception_on_overflow) OSError: [Errno -9981] Input overflowed
```

---

When I run `pocketsphinx_continuous -inmic yes -adcdev plughw:1,`0 in
terminal, it worked pretty well.